# Is it possible to use the Realtek ethernet drivers r8169 and r8125 at the same time?

Tags: networking, network-interface, kernel-modules, realtek

In addition to an existing onboard RTL8168 NIC supported via the r8169 kernel module, I installed a network card with a RTL8125B 2.5G chip in my computer-
Unfortunately my kernel doesn't support RTL8125B NICs out of the box.

Realtek [provides a driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) for the 2.5 GBit chips named r8125.
The installation script (autorun.sh) however renames an existing r8169.ko to r8169.bak for unkown reasons (I assume they collide), so that there's no more r8169 support afterwards.

Isn't it possible to run both modules at the same time to support both of my NICs?

Comment: buster-backports https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/firmware-realtek  →  Realtek RTL8125 firmware (rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw)

Comment: Please also check this (ie: kernel >= 5.9 should not need other drivers): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04. Else you can try  to first load the additional driver for RTL8125B then manually insmod the renamed driver so it claims the remaining card. Once you have this working, the problem is about how to blacklist a specific pci entry or value to a driver rather than blacklist the whole driver.